# Traffic drop after HTTPS Magento

Tags: apache-2.2, https, redirect, http, traffic

we have a Magento store, that we switched to https. Now 2 weeks after, we got a drop about 30%... What could be the cause?
I followed every step that was recommended.
I requested a reindex via search console and put a redirect into .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Did i missed out something? Our site: https://www.richhome.de/

Many Thanks

EDIT:

I put in this lines into my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

and also set `System > Configuration > Web > url_options > "Auto-redirect to Base URL = No"`

Now it redirects properly...

The question is will the Traffic recover?

Comment: can you provide complete config file? it looks like some problem in rewrite, because `http://www.richhome.de/test` redirects to `https://www.richhome.de/index.php` but i'll expect  `https://www.richhome.de/test` (and 404 on this path)

Comment: Oh okey, where do i find the config file?

Comment: It appears that you might be running Debian Wheezy.  If so the config files are in `/etc/apache2/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have both https://richhome.de/ and https://www.richhome.de/ configured. So the drop in traffic could be a result of your tracking only one of these two domains.

Anyway it's not nice to have two domains delivering the same content. Google for example treats this as [Duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) which is not good.

To do this you have to alter your apache2 config:

In your apache2 virtual host config for port 443 (which you didn't post) define only `Servername richhome.de` and remove the `ServerAlias www.richhome.de`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName richhome.de
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    # ServerAlias www.richhome.de

    # …
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add another `<VirtualHost *:443>` to redirect the www-domain to your main domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.richhome.de
    Redirect permanent / https://richhome.de/
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/richhome.de.crt
    # …
</VirtualHost>
```

You have to add the same SSL directives as the ones that letsencrypt added to the VirtualHost file for 'richhome.de'.

Before restarting apache do a config check

```
apachectl configtest
```

If you get the output `Syntax OK` then restart the webserver:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Every request for `https://www.richhome.de/` should now be redcirected to `https://richhome.de/` making tracking easier and avoiding duplicate content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can i also just put in a .htaccess 301 redirect to www.richhome.de ? Would it also do the job? Or would you recommend to switch to the non www domain.

Comment: Hi Markelus, `Redirect permanent` is a 301 redirect and Google approves of it. The above config makes richhome.de the principal domain, but in the end it's your decision which domain to choose. Maybe tomorrow I'll post a complete config. One question: do you have access to the database? Then you could configure the redirects also in `core_config_data` table of magento.

Comment: Yes i have access to the database. I now set `System > Configuration > Web > url_options > "Auto-redirect to Base URL"` to yes again. I thought that was causing the false redirects to the homepage when a http request came in, but i guess it was the .htaccess code... I also set the preferred domain in search consoles. Do you also know, if the traffic is coming back, as it was before?